# Displaying an image on JFrame window

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, drawimage

need help with trying to display an image on a JFrame. 
been using the code below, and only the window displays, and no images appear. i have also attached how my project is organized.

---

```
public class images extends JPanel {
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        Graphics g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        Image img1 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("sam.png");
        g2.drawImage(img1, 10, 10, this);
        g2.finalize();
    }

    public static void main(String[] a){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("help");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setBounds(30, 30, 300, 300);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new images());
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Don't override `paint`, you're breaking the paint chain requirements; 2. Don't load resources inside paint methods, this is a massive waste of time and resource; 3. Use `ImageIO.read` to load images, instead of `Toolkit` or `ImageIcon`, as it will will throw an exception when the image can't be loaded, rather then failing silently; 4. A `JLabel` would be a better solution over using custom painting

Comment: At a "guess", I would say that `Toolkit.getImage` can't find the image file. It will expect that the image should be located within the current working directory

Comment: Override paintComponent instead of paint, and your solution is about finding the image.
Also, if you didn't called create() you don't need to "finalize" (that the correct would be dispose()) on the Graphics2D, you will break the rest of painting associated with your screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
URL logoIconURL = getClass().getResource(""); //path of your image file

ImageIcon logoIcon = new ImageIcon(logoIconURL);

frame.setIconImage(logoIcon.getImage());
```

Comment: what bout setting the image to a specific location onto the screen

Comment: just give label and use label.setIcon() method.